# Laravel DashboardServiceProvider error when i try to create new module

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am developing an asset management webapp for my company with Laravel 8 and the Yajra Datatables package.

I have configured the project, tested the functioning of the data-tables and everything works correctly.
I now need to create two modules, Dashboard and User.

When I create the Dashboard module, with the command `php artisan make: module Dashboard` it is created correctly.
But when I try to create the User module `php artisan make: module User`  I get the error:

```
 Class 'Modules\Dashboard\Providers\DashboardServiceProvider' not found

   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:208
```

It is the first time that I use Yajra Datatables, and I don't understand the nature of the error ... I think that the problem should also have been in the creation of the Dashboard module.

Do I accept any advice or suggestions?

Comment: I think at first time it is creating the module however, can not find the provider and you try to run another command it throws an error. Even if you try to call another command it probably will throw the same error.

Comment: Yes @gguney, unfortunately I have just this behavior...is there a way to solve it? I don't understand where to start

Comment: Somewhere in your code is searching for DashboardServiceProvider inside Modules/Dashboard/Providers you can create this file manually but it will lead another errors. I don't think Yajra has make:module command. Do you have another package installed?

Comment: @gguney yes i've laravel-modules package...probably it's cause this error

Comment: Did you read this page: https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/installation-and-setup it says add some folders for autoload. After that did you clean your cache?

Comment: @gguney thank's i've appreciate your help...i've solved, the problem was the lack of Modules inside autoload in the `composer.json` file and the subsequent composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

The module classes are not loaded automatically. You need to run 'composer dump-autoload'

You can autoload your modules in the using psr-4 in the future

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    }
}
```

https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/installation-and-setup